# Agrupar numeros enteros de una lista

Tags: python

Me dan unos datos y necesito agruparlos en distintos grupos, por ejemplo si me dan el numero 22228888 necesito separarlo en 2 grupos como el 2222 y por aparte 8888. Asi con cualquier combinación que me den, aparte de contar cuantos grupos salen de cierto numero entero, por ejemplo, el anterior caso el 22228888 serian 2 grupos en cambio en 2020 serian 4 (2,0,2,0) y realmente no se como empezar soy nuevo en python gracias!

esto es lo que llevo pero no puedo avanzar

```py
y = [int(b) for b in str(number)]
dup = [x for i, x in enumerate(y) if i != y.index(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre:

1. Convertir todo el número en una cadena
2. Para ir iterando sobre cada número
3. Y así ir almacenando el estado anterior en una variable
4. Si el valor del estado anterior es el mismo que el nuevo caracter sobre el que iteramos, **acumulamos** en un pequeño buffer (otro string)
5. Si no, **el acumulado se añade a una lista y se reinicia** el proceso de acumulación:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from typing import List

def create_groups(number: int) -> List[int]:
    groups: List[int] = []
    number_to_string = str(number)
    
    first_seen = number_to_string[0]
    buffer = ""
    for value in number_to_string:
        if value == first_seen:
            # Acumulamos
            buffer = buffer + value
        else:
            # Reiniciamos
            groups.append(int(buffer))
            buffer = value
            first_seen = value
    # Anadimos el ultimo acumulado a la lista
    groups.append(int(buffer))
    return groups
```

Entonces, en lo que de como resultado la funcion `create_groups`, estarían la lista de los caracteres agrupados, y cuando aplicas la función `len()` a la resultante, sería la cantidad de grupos.

Es decir, con los test te quedarían así:

```py
def test_three_groups():
    # Given:
    test = 111222333
    expected_groups = [111, 222, 333]
    # When:
    actual_groups = create_groups(test)
    # Then:
    assert actual_groups == expected_groups

def test_one_group():
    # Given:
    test = 111
    expected_groups = [111]
    # When:
    actual_groups = create_groups(test)
    # Then:
    assert actual_groups == expected_groups

def test_right_qty_grops():
    # Given:
    test = 1123345
    expected_qty = 5
    # When:
    actual_qty = len(create_groups(test))
    # Then:
    assert actual_qty == expected_qty
```

Resultando de los test:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]